# pulse animation on existing markers (google maps)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to add a pulse animation [like](https://github.com/mapshakers/leaflet-icon-pulse) this to my existing markers on a checkbox click, how can I do this?

Comment: If I could atleast add a class to my marker,  like this
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    map: map,
    class:'className'
    draggable: true
});
I can add an animation like this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646351/animate-google-map-markers?rq=1 , but adding a class is not working.

Comment: Very similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/13797995/488666

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not as easy as you it seems it ought to be. I've just been doing this exact same thing and have had some success.

The most straightforward way is to use an animated gif as your marker.

If you want to do a CSS animation and are a bit more comfortable with JS you can add a wrapper around all your makers using the code below (after adding all your markers. It creates a new overlay to the marker pane and gives that a class of `.marker-layer`.

One problem with this is that Google Maps tries to render icons using canvas if it can, which means you don't have access to them in this way. You therefore have to pass `optimized: false,` to the marker options to then get access to the marker.

```
const markerlayer = new google.maps.OverlayView();
markerlayer.draw = function () {
    this.getPanes().markerLayer.classList.add('marker-layer');
};
markerlayer.setMap(map);
```